# Reference requests for commentaries/books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am a high school student. And am looking for commentaries like these ones by Prof. KD Joshi. 
http://mathjeecommentary.blogspot.in

By "like these" I mean:-

- similar style of explaining and commenting on problems(as close as possible)
- pertaining to **any topic** .
- not necessarily related to exams on which he has commented. But the questions must be good.

Also, if anyone knows his book, "Educative JEE mathematics". Is there any other book like that, which presents the problems and solutions (first hints then solution) and expounds on them with the same vigour and clarity?

One impact these commentaries and book had on me was to change the thought process I had. I could clearly see and reflect on Polya's problem-solving techniques being beautifully implemented here.

Don't let the constraints constraint you from recommending other books/commentaries if you think they are of comparable level, or if you think they can change one's thought process.

***Edit*** :- Some similar books I found :-

- The Cauchy-Schwarz Master class  by    J. Michael Steele
- The art and craft of problem solving by Paul Zeitz

I would be really blessed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

**How to prove it by D. Vellemen** is good book to learn basics needed for university math and also it teaches about various proof techniques and how to use them. It is the best resource for high school student willing to go into some serious math